# Autostart chromium browser other user than pi

Tags: lxde, kiosk

I'm trying to get following to work. Unfortunately, everything I tried so far did not.

- I have a Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspbian (Buster) installed.
- I have 3 users (root, pi and "kiosk"). The user "kiosk" is no sudoer (and should never be).
- auto-login to GUI for user "kiosk" is in effect

Now I want for the user "kiosk" (and only for this user) to auto-start chromium.

So far I tried the following

1. Added "LXDE-kiosk" folder in `/etc/xdg/lxsession/`, copied contents of `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE` and adjusted autostart file. However chromium was not started on reboot..
2. I added a script to `home/kiosk` which should start a chromium browser and called it in crontab with a  `@reboot` entry. This did not work either. Later I found out that no GUI app should be startet via cron.

To be honest, I don't understand why the first option did not work. Is it even possible to have different autostart options for different users?
When adjusting the "LXDE-pi autostart" file, everything works as expected.

(Edit: I also tried it with the old location `/home/kiosk/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart` with no luck).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option did not work because `LXDE-pi` is not a folder belonging to the user `pi`, despite the name. It's a folder with a global config for a *desktop environment profile* called `LXDE-pi`.

I'd concentrate on getting `/home/kiosk/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart` to work. Put a simple script there which creates a file in `/tmp` or something similar, and see if that works. If not, find out why. Most likely, it's because you're still using the `LXDE-pi` profile and the path should be `/home/kiosk/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`.

AFAIK another option is to create a *.desktop file in `/home/kiosk/.config/autostart`.

Once a simple script works, try out Chromium. My advice is to run it interactively with `kiosk` user in the beginning, to make sure it can run at all.

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed `/home/kiosk/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` (so changing to LXDE-pi) did the trick. Great. :)

Answer (score 1):

Install gnome-tweeks. There is an option called Startup Applications there.
Click on the + to add your startup apps. I'm using rpi4.